# Unable to understand master-chef contract in pancake-swap

Tags: contract-development, decentralized-exchange, pancakeswap, swaps

**I am going through a master chef contract in pancake swap farm and I am unable to understand some points in that contract.

- —>what does reward debt means in user info, Is it the rewards he
  need to get or it is the rewards he already harvested
- —>what does
  the update pool function is for, what it was doing
- —>what does
  updating the staking pool is for, why we are updating all the
  allocation points to the first pool
- —>what is the dev address

**

```
 pragma solidity 0.6.12;
//Doubt1-->why we are updating pool[0] by total allocation pointsfrom other farms/3
//Doubt2-->why migrate approval the value is 0
import '@pancakeswap/pancake-swap-lib/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol';
import '@pancakeswap/pancake-swap-lib/contracts/token/BEP20/IBEP20.sol';
import '@pancakeswap/pancake-swap-lib/contracts/token/BEP20/SafeBEP20.sol';
import '@pancakeswap/pancake-swap-lib/contracts/access/Ownable.sol';

import "./CakeToken.sol";
import "./SyrupBar.sol";

// import "@nomiclabs/buidler/console.sol";

interface IMigratorChef {
    // Perform LP token migration from legacy PancakeSwap to CakeSwap.
    // Take the current LP token address and return the new LP token address.
    // Migrator should have full access to the caller's LP token.
    // Return the new LP token address.
    //
    // XXX Migrator must have allowance access to PancakeSwap LP tokens.
    // CakeSwap must mint EXACTLY the same amount of CakeSwap LP tokens or
    // else something bad will happen. Traditional PancakeSwap does not
    // do that so be careful!
    function migrate(IBEP20 token) external returns (IBEP20);
}

// MasterChef is the master of Cake. He can make Cake and he is a fair guy.
//
// Note that it's ownable and the owner wields tremendous power. The ownership
// will be transferred to a governance smart contract once CAKE is sufficiently
// distributed and the community can show to govern itself.
//
// Have fun reading it. Hopefully it's bug-free. God bless.
contract MasterChef is Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using SafeBEP20 for IBEP20;

    // Info of each user.
    struct UserInfo {
        uint256 amount;     // How many LP tokens the user has provided.
        uint256 rewardDebt; // Reward debt. See explanation below.//is rewarddept is how much reward he received tillnow or how much reward he needs to
        //
        // We do some fancy math here. Basically, any point in time, the amount of CAKEs
        // entitled to a user but is pending to be distributed is:
        //
        //   pending reward = (user.amount * pool.accCakePerShare) - user.rewardDebt
        //
        // Whenever a user deposits or withdraws LP tokens to a pool. Here's what happens:
        //   1. The pool's `accCakePerShare` (and `lastRewardBlock`) gets updated.
        //   2. User receives the pending reward sent to his/her address.
        //   3. User's `amount` gets updated.
        //   4. User's `rewardDebt` gets updated.
    }

    // Info of each pool.
    struct PoolInfo {
        IBEP20 lpToken;           // Address of LP token contract.
        uint256 allocPoint;       // How many allocation points assigned to this pool. CAKEs to distribute per block.
        uint256 lastRewardBlock;  // Last block number that CAKEs distribution occurs.//not understood
        uint256 accCakePerShare; // Accumulated CAKEs per share, times 1e12. See below.
    }

    // The CAKE TOKEN!
    CakeToken public cake;
    // The SYRUP TOKEN!
    SyrupBar public syrup;
    // Dev address.
    address public devaddr;
    // CAKE tokens created per block.
    uint256 public cakePerBlock;
    // Bonus muliplier for early cake makers.
    uint256 public BONUS_MULTIPLIER = 1;
    // The migrator contract. It has a lot of power. Can only be set through governance (owner).
    IMigratorChef public migrator;

    // Info of each pool.
    PoolInfo[] public poolInfo;
    // Info of each user that stakes LP tokens.
    mapping (uint256 => mapping (address => UserInfo)) public userInfo;
    // Total allocation points. Must be the sum of all allocation points in all pools.
    uint256 public totalAllocPoint = 0;
    // The block number when CAKE mining starts.
    uint256 public startBlock;

    event Deposit(address indexed user, uint256 indexed pid, uint256 amount);
    event Withdraw(address indexed user, uint256 indexed pid, uint256 amount);
    event EmergencyWithdraw(address indexed user, uint256 indexed pid, uint256 amount);

    constructor(
        CakeToken _cake,
        SyrupBar _syrup,
        address _devaddr,
        uint256 _cakePerBlock,
        uint256 _startBlock
    ) public {
        cake = _cake;
        syrup = _syrup;
        devaddr = _devaddr;
        cakePerBlock = _cakePerBlock;
        startBlock = _startBlock;

        // staking pool
        //adding the pool to the farm
        poolInfo.push(PoolInfo({
            lpToken: _cake,
            allocPoint: 1000,
            lastRewardBlock: startBlock,
            accCakePerShare: 0
        }));

        totalAllocPoint = 1000;

    }

    function updateMultiplier(uint256 multiplierNumber) public onlyOwner {
        BONUS_MULTIPLIER = multiplierNumber;
        //determining the cake tokens allocated to each farm
    }

    function poolLength() external view returns (uint256) {
        return poolInfo.length;
        //Determine how many pools we have
    }

    // Add a new lp to the pool. Can only be called by the owner.
    // XXX DO NOT add the same LP token more than once. Rewards will be messed up if you do.
    function add(uint256 _allocPoint, IBEP20 _lpToken, bool _withUpdate) public onlyOwner {
        if (_withUpdate) {
            massUpdatePools();
        }
        uint256 lastRewardBlock = block.number > startBlock ? block.number : startBlock;
        totalAllocPoint = totalAllocPoint.add(_allocPoint);
        poolInfo.push(PoolInfo({
            lpToken: _lpToken,
            allocPoint: _allocPoint,
            lastRewardBlock: lastRewardBlock,
            accCakePerShare: 0
        }));
        updateStakingPool();
    }

    // Update the given pool's CAKE allocation point. Can only be called by the owner.
    function set(uint256 _pid, uint256 _allocPoint, bool _withUpdate) public onlyOwner {
        if (_withUpdate) {
            massUpdatePools();
        }
        uint256 prevAllocPoint = poolInfo[_pid].allocPoint;
        poolInfo[_pid].allocPoint = _allocPoint;
        if (prevAllocPoint != _allocPoint) {
            totalAllocPoint = totalAllocPoint.sub(prevAllocPoint).add(_allocPoint);
            updateStakingPool();
        }
    }

    function updateStakingPool() internal {
        uint256 length = poolInfo.length;
        uint256 points = 0;
        for (uint256 pid = 1; pid < length; ++pid) {
            points = points.add(poolInfo[pid].allocPoint);
        }
        if (points != 0) {
            points = points.div(3);
            totalAllocPoint = totalAllocPoint.sub(poolInfo[0].allocPoint).add(points);
            poolInfo[0].allocPoint = points;//setting first pool allocation points to totalpool allocation/3
        }
    }

    // Set the migrator contract. Can only be called by the owner.
    function setMigrator(IMigratorChef _migrator) public onlyOwner {
        migrator = _migrator;//setting the migrator who can able to migrate the lp tokens
    }

    // Migrate lp token to another lp contract. Can be called by anyone. We trust that migrator contract is good.
    function migrate(uint256 _pid) public {
        require(address(migrator) != address(0), "migrate: no migrator");//checking whether the migrator address is valid
        PoolInfo storage pool = poolInfo[_pid];//taking the specific pool
        IBEP20 lpToken = pool.lpToken;//grabbing the lp token associated with that pool
        uint256 bal = lpToken.balanceOf(address(this));//getting the balance of old lptoken
        lpToken.safeApprove(address(migrator), bal);//approving the migrator to spend our balance
        IBEP20 newLpToken = migrator.migrate(lpToken);//migrating old token to new token
        require(bal == newLpToken.balanceOf(address(this)), "migrate: bad");//cheking if the balance of the old token and new token pool are same
        pool.lpToken = newLpToken;//setting the pool with newlptoken
    }

    // Return reward multiplier over the given _from to _to block.
   function getMultiplier(uint256 _from, uint256 _to) public view returns (uint256) {
        return _to.sub(_from).mul(BONUS_MULTIPLIER);//multiplying the multiplier from blocks between current block and last block
    }

    // View function to see pending CAKEs on frontend.
    function pendingCake(uint256 _pid, address _user) external view returns (uint256) {
        PoolInfo storage pool = poolInfo[_pid];//getting the specific pool with it id
        UserInfo storage user = userInfo[_pid][_user];//getting user belongs to that pool
        uint256 accCakePerShare = pool.accCakePerShare;//getting the accumulated cakepershare in that pool
        uint256 lpSupply = pool.lpToken.balanceOf(address(this));//how many lptokens are there in that pool
        if (block.number > pool.lastRewardBlock && lpSupply != 0) {
            uint256 multiplier = getMultiplier(pool.lastRewardBlock, block.number);
            uint256 cakeReward = multiplier.mul(cakePerBlock).mul(pool.allocPoint).div(totalAllocPoint);//calculating the cake reward
            accCakePerShare = accCakePerShare.add(cakeReward.mul(1e12).div(lpSupply));//accumulated cake per each share
        }
        return user.amount.mul(accCakePerShare).div(1e12).sub(user.rewardDebt);//get the pending cakes which are rewarded to us to harvest
    }

    // Update reward variables for all pools. Be careful of gas spending!
    function massUpdatePools() public {
        uint256 length = poolInfo.length;
        for (uint256 pid = 0; pid < length; ++pid) {
            updatePool(pid);
        }
    }


    // Update reward variables of the given pool to be up-to-date.
    function updatePool(uint256 _pid) public {
        PoolInfo storage pool = poolInfo[_pid];//specifying the single pool
        if (block.number <= pool.lastRewardBlock) {
            return;//not understood
        }
        uint256 lpSupply = pool.lpToken.balanceOf(address(this));
        if (lpSupply == 0) {//if there is no lp supply 
            pool.lastRewardBlock = block.number;//setting the last reward block of the present pool to the present reward pool because if there is no lp supply in the pool therre is sno activity from the last pool 
            return;
        }
        uint256 multiplier = getMultiplier(pool.lastRewardBlock, block.number);
        uint256 cakeReward = multiplier.mul(cakePerBlock).mul(pool.allocPoint).div(totalAllocPoint);//calculating the cake rewards still pending for this pool 
        cake.mint(devaddr, cakeReward.div(10));//
        cake.mint(address(syrup), cakeReward);
        pool.accCakePerShare = pool.accCakePerShare.add(cakeReward.mul(1e12).div(lpSupply));
        pool.lastRewardBlock = block.number;
    }

    // Deposit LP tokens to MasterChef for CAKE allocation.
    function deposit(uint256 _pid, uint256 _amount) public {

        require (_pid != 0, 'deposit CAKE by staking');

        PoolInfo storage pool = poolInfo[_pid];//assigning the specific pool with pool id
        UserInfo storage user = userInfo[_pid][msg.sender];//assigning the user for that pid
        updatePool(_pid);//updates the accCakereward
        if (user.amount > 0) {
            //sends the pending amount to the user
            //if user had already added money into the pools
            //checking if user provided lp tokens are greater than zero 
            uint256 pending = user.amount.mul(pool.accCakePerShare).div(1e12).sub(user.rewardDebt);//why we are subtracting the reward dept
            if(pending > 0) {
                safeCakeTransfer(msg.sender, pending);
            }
        }
        if (_amount > 0) {
            //updates the user amount
            //whenever the user deposit it should be gone into the pool that user is depositig into
            //transferring lptokens from user address to pool
            pool.lpToken.safeTransferFrom(address(msg.sender), address(this), _amount);
            user.amount = user.amount.add(_amount);//adding how many tokens user had provided in his account
        }
        //updates the user reward dept
        user.rewardDebt = user.amount.mul(pool.accCakePerShare).div(1e12);
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, _pid, _amount);
    }

    // Withdraw LP tokens from MasterChef.
    function withdraw(uint256 _pid, uint256 _amount) public {

        require (_pid != 0, 'withdraw CAKE by unstaking');
        PoolInfo storage pool = poolInfo[_pid];
        UserInfo storage user = userInfo[_pid][msg.sender];
        require(user.amount >= _amount, "withdraw: not good");//the amount of lp tokens he had staked need to less than or equal to th eamount 

        updatePool(_pid);
        uint256 pending = user.amount.mul(pool.accCakePerShare).div(1e12).sub(user.rewardDebt);
        if(pending > 0) {
            safeCakeTransfer(msg.sender, pending);
        }
        if(_amount > 0) {
            user.amount = user.amount.sub(_amount);//subtracting the amount from the number of lptokens user had staked
            pool.lpToken.safeTransfer(address(msg.sender), _amount);//transfering the lptokens from pool to user 
        }
        user.rewardDebt = user.amount.mul(pool.accCakePerShare).div(1e12);
        emit Withdraw(msg.sender, _pid, _amount);
    }

    // Stake CAKE tokens to MasterChef
    function enterStaking(uint256 _amount) public {
        PoolInfo storage pool = poolInfo[0];
        UserInfo storage user = userInfo[0][msg.sender];
        updatePool(0);
        if (user.amount > 0) {
            uint256 pending = user.amount.mul(pool.accCakePerShare).div(1e12).sub(user.rewardDebt);
            if(pending > 0) {
                safeCakeTransfer(msg.sender, pending);
            }
        }
        if(_amount > 0) {
            pool.lpToken.safeTransferFrom(address(msg.sender), address(this), _amount);
            user.amount = user.amount.add(_amount);
        }
        user.rewardDebt = user.amount.mul(pool.accCakePerShare).div(1e12);

        syrup.mint(msg.sender, _amount);
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, 0, _amount);
    }

    // Withdraw CAKE tokens from STAKING.
    function leaveStaking(uint256 _amount) public {
        PoolInfo storage pool = poolInfo[0];
        UserInfo storage user = userInfo[0][msg.sender];
        require(user.amount >= _amount, "withdraw: not good");
        updatePool(0);
        uint256 pending = user.amount.mul(pool.accCakePerShare).div(1e12).sub(user.rewardDebt);
        if(pending > 0) {
            safeCakeTransfer(msg.sender, pending);
        }
        if(_amount > 0) {
            user.amount = user.amount.sub(_amount);
            pool.lpToken.safeTransfer(address(msg.sender), _amount);
        }
        user.rewardDebt = user.amount.mul(pool.accCakePerShare).div(1e12);

        syrup.burn(msg.sender, _amount);
        emit Withdraw(msg.sender, 0, _amount);
    }

    // Withdraw without caring about rewards. EMERGENCY ONLY.
    function emergencyWithdraw(uint256 _pid) public {
        PoolInfo storage pool = poolInfo[_pid];
        UserInfo storage user = userInfo[_pid][msg.sender];
        pool.lpToken.safeTransfer(address(msg.sender), user.amount);
        emit EmergencyWithdraw(msg.sender, _pid, user.amount);
        user.amount = 0;
        user.rewardDebt = 0;
    }

    // Safe cake transfer function, just in case if rounding error causes pool to not have enough CAKEs.
    function safeCakeTransfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) internal {
        syrup.safeCakeTransfer(_to, _amount);
    }

    // Update dev address by the previous dev.
    function dev(address _devaddr) public {
        require(msg.sender == devaddr, "dev: wut?");
        devaddr = _devaddr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the contracts as text.

Comment: I have updated it

Answer (score 2):

1. Dev Address - Some percentage of cake minted is sent to the dev address. For every 100 cake, 10 is sent to dev address. The dev address will then burn it.
2. Update pool fn - Straight forward, it is used to update the number of cake to be emitted/allocated for each pool.
3. Updating the staking pool - Changing LP token details.
4. Reward debt - Whatever the user has received so far.

Comment: In Updating the staking pool ,why we are assigning the all the sum(allocationpoints of all pools)/3 to the first pool.allocation points